# Mac stuck on "The wine configuration in /user/... is being updated"

Tags: macos, windows, wine

[image]

That's what we're looking at right now. I've tried to download Wine Bottler but when i tried to run an MSI file with wine bottler for the first time this is what i get

how do i fix this?

Comment: Depends o the version of wine bottler an the app you are trying to install

Answer (score 1):

Found this question on Super User:

https://superuser.com/questions/1318059/wineboot-hangs-and-does-not-complete

According to the answer it is a known bug with the Homebrew version:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/26384

The workaround is to use the official version:

https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/macosx/download.html